# How to efficiently match the elements of one data.frame to another?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

**Example Data**

Consider the two following data.frames as an example

```
set.seed(12)
d1 = cbind(
   expand.grid(1:4,LETTERS[1:3]),
   rnorm(12,10,1)
)[sample(1:12),]

d2 = as.data.frame(
       cbind(
          sample(c(1,2,4),900, replace=TRUE),
          sample(LETTERS[1:3],900,replace=TRUE)
       )[sample(1:900),]
     )

names(d1) = c("x","y","z")
names(d2) = c("x","y")
```

`d1` is small and contain all possible combinations of `x` and `y` and contains the `z` variable. `d2` is much longer, does not necessarily contain all possible combinations of `x` and `y` and does not contain the `z` variable. In both variables, there is no logical order for the combinations of `x` and `y` (as in the example).

**Goal**

How can I enter the values of the `z` variable from `d1` into `d2` respecting the combination of `x` and `y`?

**Bad solution**

```
d2$z = 0
for (x in unique(d1$x))
{
  for (y in unique(d1$y))
  {
    d2$z[d2$x == x & d2$y == y] = d1$z[d1$x == x & d1$y == y]
  }
}
head(d2)
  x y         z
1 2 B  9.727704
2 1 C  9.893536
3 2 A 11.577169
4 1 A  8.519432
5 4 C  8.706118
6 2 B  9.727704
```

However, it is terribly slow when the data.frames are a few millions rows long. Also, it is not very flexible.

**Is there a better alternative?**

Comment: Hmm, isn't this just `merge(d1, d2, by = c("x", "y"))`?

Comment: I started to answer this but David closed it.  I would look into data.table package for big data (but smaller than RAM)

Comment: Yes it appears to do the same thing (after reordering the rows). A much better solution...eventually the best? I will try on my big data.frames to see if the CPU time is bearable. Thank you

Comment: @DeanMacGregor there are `data.table` examples in the dupe. No need to post additional answers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm not saying you shouldn't have closed it but to the extent that OP just takes your `merge` comment without looking at other question, data.table would be good.

Comment: I would love to see the data.table solutions indeed! I am using data.table and the `merge` function is still pretty slow. I am hoping that `data.table` could eventually make it a little faster.